# RHEL yum Package Installation from Repository of Differing Release Number

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, package-management, yum, rpm

I have two RHEL machines. One runs RHEL 6.9, and the other runs RHEL 7.7.

I have access to *local* copies of both the RHEL 6.9 and the RHEL 7.7 repositories. This is the *only* repository access I have.

The RHEL 6.9 repository contains a package for SVN 1.6.11. The RHEL 7.7 repository contains a package for SVN 1.7.14.

I would like to install SVN 1.7.14 on the RHEL 6.9 machine. When, on the RHEL 6.9 machine, I point yum at the RHEL 7.7 repository (where the SVN 1.7.14 package lives) and try to install SVN 1.7.14, I get many errors about conflicting dependent packages. Of course, this is not a surprise.

How may I install SVN 1.7.14 on the RHEL 6.9 machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to work.

It is like saying: I want an engine from Lamborgini in my Peugeot 107. It is possible with a lot of work. Thou the result is neither Lambo nor Peugeot. And it is not worth the work.

You can take the source rpm from 7.7 repository, rebuild it using `mock` for RHEL 6. You will hit some missing or old deps, so you will have to rebuild them too. And it will go recursively and you may spend weeks or months on this task.

Considering that RHEL6 is going to be EOLed this November, you may rather spend your time migrating to RHEL 8.

Comment: Yeah, sure seems that way. Looks like some third-party orgs have done the hard work and created repos for newer SVN for older RHEL, but I have no access to those repos. Unfortunately, I don't have access to source repos either. RHEL 8 is not available, and migrating the RHEL 6.9 host to RHEL 7.7 is deemed too risky to the stability of our work. So, looks like we're pretty stuck. Appreciate you taking the time to respond and your mention of mock (I'd not previously heard of it; may be useful in the future). Accepted as answer.

Comment: RHEL 8 and CentOS 8 are available. I guess you meant that it is not an option for you.

Comment: That is correct.